# is that possible to call dataflow using cloud run in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-run

Is that possible to call dataflow using cloud run in GCP or any other alternative ways to run dataflow every    30 mins.
I would thankful if someone share reference material for implementation procedure.

[Running dataflow locally on Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324996/running-dataflow-locally-on-cloud-run)

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Dataflow Flex Templates.  These allow you to package up a Beam pipeline into a set of artifacts that can then be started through a REST call.  You could then use Cloud Scheduler to invoke that REST call.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

- Given that you want to invoke dataflow every 30 mins or at a predefined/regular interval, consider using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/). Cloud Scheduler is a fully-managed cron like service and it will allow you to say invoke a URL, every 30 mins or whatever is the frequency that you would want.
- The URL that you are invoking can be a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions). The code inside your function will be the execution code that launches your Dataflow template.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a [Flex template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) and invoking the dataflow job using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.flexTemplates/launch) and [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/).

If you want to run a regular dataflow job, you could follow Romin's advice and use a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) to execute custom code to launch a dataflow job and invoke the function from the Cloud Scheduler. This is more complex IMHO. Using flex templates might just be easier.